# Is there a way to allow Tab key navigation in HtmlEditor tables with the html_editor_enhanced package?

Tags: flutter, editor

I work on Flutter Web project.
I use HtmlEditor with package html_editor_enhanced.
When I set a table in editor , then I can't skip to the next column with TAB key.
That's pretty standard action in a text editor.

Well I don't know what to do with this.
I am expecting that after taping TAB key , I will skip to the next table column.